# Mongodb & Symfony QueryBuilder

Tags: mongodb, symfony, query-builder

Does someone know where I can find some informations about Mongodb QueryBuilder in Symfony2 please? Maybe some examples or some tutorials.
I googled the question but didn't find something good enough..
More specifically I want to retrieve a field in a document based on the embedded document.
Here is an example of document :

```
{
"name":"Foo",
"age":"25",
"gender":"Male",
"products":[
        {
            "name":"Apple",
            "price":"12.00",
            "date":"2015-12-02"
        },
        {
            "name":"Banana",
            "price":"9.00",
            "date":"201-11-31"
        },
]
```

}

And I want to retrieve the name "Foo" based on the date in products array.
At the moment I use distinct() to list all fields in products.

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

Comment: Thanks Malcolm, I've been on that page, but I wanted something with more complex examples, if it exists of course :D

Comment: I would suggest you change your question on how to achieve some specific query, because right now, it is up for debate if this question should be closed or no :-/

Comment: Alright, there you go ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple doctrine mongodb example for EmbedMany in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/1ntx/simple-doctrine-mongodb-example-for-embed-many-in-symfony)

Assume that a `League` may have one or many `Team`s so it is a [Embed Many](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/embedded-mapping.html) like in your case. Full example is above. If you want more info then I think [first 5 posts](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/symfony) are enough for you.

**EXAMPLE USAGE**

```
->findOneByProperty('name', 'Premiership')
```

**REPO**

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;

class LeagueRepository extends DocumentRepository
{
    /**
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $data
     *
     * @return array|null|object
     */
    public function findOneByProperty($field, $data)
    {
        return
            $this->createQueryBuilder('League')
                ->field($field)->equals($data)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

**DUMMY DATA**

```
db.getCollection('league').find({})
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564fa07add576ebcf90041ac"),
    "name" : "Super Lig",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-11-20T22:36:42.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564fa081dd576ebbf90041ad"),
    "name" : "Premiership",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-11-20T22:36:49.000Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-11-20T22:37:33.000Z"),
    "teams" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("564fa0a6dd576ef2f80041ad"),
            "name" : "Arsenal",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-11-20T22:37:26.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("564fa0addd576ebaf90041ad"),
            "name" : "Liverpool",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-11-20T22:37:33.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wonderfull! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, enjoy. If it solves your problem, please accept it so that others can benefit from it. Thanks

Comment: Based on the example given for League document, how can you display the teams name in twig, I tried to do $var.products but doesnt work as it is an array. How does Symfony handle this please? I am only able to get the parent documents fields (name, age gender etc..) but not the products fields

Comment: You need to run `foreach` on `$league` and get `team` within the loop. Just a classic way if you. There are many of examples out there. Something like: `foreach ($leagues as $league) { $team = $league->getTeam(); }` so on. Just Google it.

Comment: Alright, thanks man! I'll try it once home, and sorry for that nooby questions...I am new to symfony :p

Comment: That's fine. You'll find many useful examples regarding to symfony [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/symfony)

Comment: Yea I am reading it :p but the thing is sometime I don't know where should I put the command, in the controller or in the twig. For the example the foreach loop must be in the controller right? just after the function league? not in the twig